# How to use javascript confirmation method on code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

```
else if (Result == 1)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Test", "return  confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? This action cannot be undone.')", true);                              
  FSI.DeleteINsertData(ID.ToString(), No.ToString());
}
```

I have a js confirmation on code behind. I want to continue process when the user click "yes", otherway , user click "no", do nothing. it is in else if statement.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `if(confirm('message')) { // do something } else {return false}`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Response.Write("<script>confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? This action cannot be undone.');</script>");
```

Might Work!

Comment: Won't work. This has exactly the same problem as the original code; writing some script to the page output does NOT pause the server-side code, which will continue and delete the data before the user has even read that confirmation box, let alone clicked anything. This is fundamentally the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that what you want to do is pause the server-side code (before you delete anything) while you wait for some client-side code to execute (throwing up the confirmation box to make sure the user does want to perform the delete). This simply isn't the way things work.

All the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(...) call does is tell the server that it should include that script when it sends the response to the client. It doesn't then pause and send the script; instead it just carries on, executing the deletion and *then* the page and script gets sent to the client. You can't change that behaviour - it's a fundamental part of how server-side web programming works.

Your options really are to have the delete button/link that they clicked in the first place throw up the confirmation box before you even go to the server (cancelling the form-submission or link-click if they've changed their minds), or alternatively to have the server reply to that submission/click with a confirmation page that requires them to click another button, which then goes back to the server again to actually perform the delete.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make merge between server side and Client side.
You can add your script as code behind:

            `string scriptStr = "<script>var confirmation = confirm('something');
                                if(confirmation){document.getelementbyid('button').click();}
                                else{//something else}</script>";
            RegisterStartupScript("ScriptFunction", scriptStr );`

```
and then in your code behind handle the button click event.
This may works for you.
```